# Catalog Price rules are not carried over to the shopping cart and checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

I'm having troubles with Catalog Price rules. I have a rule that says YY% discount on products of manufacturer "X" for all members of customer-group "resellers"

I save and apply the rule (and cron is running so it updates every day), yet it does not work as expected.

The discount correctly shows on the product page, yet once you add the product to the cart, it reverts back to the original price, and this is the same for the actual checkout.

Yet if I create an order from the backend for the same customer, the discount is correctly applied...

Both the cart and the checkout use the stock base/default .phtml files for display of products/price/tax etc...

I've been experiencing this issue with Magento 1.8x, and just upgraded to 1.9.0.1 and still the same issue.

Comment: What other 3rd party extensions are you using?

Comment: @JamesAllwood Currently these extensions are installed:

Amasty_Base
Amasty_Catcopy
Amasty_Imgupload
Amasty_Notfound
Amasty_Number
Amasty_Oaction
Amasty_Paction
Amasty_Pgrid
Aoe_Scheduler
Aoe_TemplateHints
AvS_ScopeHint
Bubble_Queryfier
Cm_RedisSession
Creare_CreareSeoCore
Creare_CreareSeoSitemap
Ebizmarts_AbandonedCart
Ebizmarts_Autoresponder   
Ebizmarts_MageMonkey    
Ebizmarts_Mandrill
FireGento_MageSetup  
FlyWebdesign_PaypalFee  
Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus 
Hackathon_LocaleFallback
IntegerNet_Autoshipping
IntegerNet_RemoveCustomerAccountLinks

Comment: @JamesAllwood - exactly the same extensions/setup as in my dev setup, where everything is working like a charm. Have been studying database differences, yet can't seem to find what's causing this.

Comment: And staging site runs on same server?

Comment: Yup. Just different DB and different directory.

Comment: @JamesAllwood Just compared DB structure, Same tables, same fields. Compared DB rule data as well, also looks exactly the same.

Comment: Hmm, what about cache, is it enabled in both site? Are sessions saved in the same way files/db?

Comment: Check your database, make sure the majority of tables are innodb - it sounds like innodb has failed to start and resulted in everything defaulting to myisam

Comment: @choco-loo Both instances are running of the same MariaDB engine and innodb is enabled and the majority - if not all - tables are innodb.

Comment: @JamesAllwood Just disabled cache on my live site - no change. Sessions in live are saved in Redis and in file on dev.

Comment: OK, so we've identified one difference then. As unlikely as it may be, to cancel it out of the equation, can you try switching session storage temporarily to files on the live?

Comment: @JamesAllwood just did and guess what... no change :(

Comment: Just dumped the database and imported it into a new one and pointed the live site to this DB - didn't help either.

Comment: used the magento db repair tool 1.2 to compare and fix issues between dev and live, regenerated the rules, reindexed, cache still disabled. Codebase 100% the same (complete composer.json setup) - live db just has way more products. I'm flabbergasted, it still doesn't use the right price when adding to cart. Somebody a clue on where to look next?

Comment: I think there is probably an issue around here Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::processFrontFinalPrice give me a few mins and I'll put a more helpfull answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a set X to Y solution, but may help you debug this.

I'm not 100% at this point how the catalog price rules are applied to the products in the catalog, but what I can say is that they are applied differently in the catalog to in the cart.

`Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::processFrontFinalPrice()` is where the catalog rules are applied to the cart items, so for example if I simply add return $this straight away I can replicated the exact behaviour your seeing, with the rules applied in the catalog, and indeed the admin as those are added in `processAdminFinalPrice()` but the cart rules are not applied.

```
    public function prepareCatalogProductCollectionPrices(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        return $this;
        ...
```

Not a great answer but atleast this gives you somewhere to look.

Does the same problem happen when you don't set a specific customer group ID but instead select them all?

Comment: "Does the same problem happen when you don't set a specific customer group ID but instead select them all?"

Well.. I just applied the discount to all websites and all customer groups including Not-logged-in; and hit save&apply. It worked as expected. First I removed not-logged-in and hit save&apply. It still was OK. Then I removed other unwanted groups/websites for this rule and much to my surprise it still works. I still have no idea what went/is wrong, so I'll keep the question open for a few days while monitoring the situation.... Thanks so far!

Comment: Although I have deleted and recreated the catalog rule many many times, I can confirm that it seems to work in my -original- live db as well (last test was after a dump/import in a new db) - just by selecting a few more groups, save&apply and then removing these groups. Funny thing is that I don't receive a message to clear the cache anymore... While experiencing the problems I got this message everytime after hitting save&apply on this rule. **The issue seems to be gone yet I have no clue what or why**